# Document Name within a PHP include

Tags: php, html

I have 16 Documents with a php include in them to include a php template like this:

```
<?php include("templates/template.php"); ?>
```

Inside that template there is a little bit of PHP which finds the document name and prints it. The problem is that for the php document to be included its PHP is processed (Naturally because its PHP), this means that the document name finder is finding the name of the template and not the main document. What I am trying to do is have 16 PHP Files which act as a front end and are accessed by the User, these files include the Template file which finds the name of the accessed file and pulls html code from another file into the body of the template. This means that the content for the file is external to the Structure of the site and allows a level of simplicity for basic editing (I.E. The client can edit their website). As I stated above my method has a simple problem what I am trying to figure out is if anyway knows how to do this.The Template file is pasted below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
<!--
var screenwidth = screen.width;
if (screenwidth < 1180){
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ldrop.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
}
else
{
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/drop.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
}
// -->
</script> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Alignment Courses</title> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
</head>
<body onload="makerequest('templates/quote.php','quote'); return false;makerequest('editing/<?php echo basename(__FILE__, '.' . pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); ?>.php','main')">
<div id="menu"><a href="index.html"><img src="webpics/logo.png" width="225" height="150" onmouseover="this.src='webpics/logoinv.png'" onmouseout="this.src='webpics/logo.png'" style="float:left" alt="Exit To Banner"/></a>
<div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="webpics/Yoga Health.png" alt="Yoga Health Townsville" width="458" height="43" vspace="20"
onmouseover="this.src='webpics/Yoga Health Inv.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='webpics/Yoga Health.png'"/></a><a href="gallery.php" class="visit">visit the photo gallery</a></div> 
<div id="nav" class="mainmenu"> 
<ul>
<li class="menu1"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu2"><a href="#">Classes</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="daily.php">Daily</a></li>
<li><a href="beginner.php">Beginner</a></li>
<li><a href="alignment.php">Alignment</a></li>
<li><a href="prepare.php">Preparation</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu3"><a href="#">Family Yoga</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="family.php">Family Yoga</a></li>
<li><a href="kids.php">Childrens Yoga</a></li>
<li><a href="prenatal.php">Prenatal Yoga</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu4"><a href="#">Prices</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="prices.php">Classes</a></li>
<li><a href="purchase.php">Equipment</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu5"><a href="events.php">Events/Workshops</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="dance.php">Dance</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu6"><a href="teachers.php">Our Teachers</a></li>
<li class="menu7"><a href="contact.php">Location</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
<div id="content"><div id="sidebar"><div id="sidebar">
        <p><strong class="MyriadPromain"><em>Contacts</em></strong><br />
          <span class="MyriadProcontact">Shop 3, 262 Woolcock Street, Currajong, 4812 <br />
          <a href="mailto:info@yogahealth.net.au">Information: info@yogahealth.net.au</a><br />
          <a href="mailto:bookings@yogahealth.net.au">Bookings: bookings@yogahealth.net.au</a><br />
          Phone: 07 47 751 154<br />
          Mobile: 0410 085 054<br /><br /></span>
          <span class="ArialGroup">For Enquiries Regarding Group Bookings<br /><a href="documents/Group Bookings.pdf">Click Here</a></span>
        </p>
        <p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Yoga-Health-Townsville/140216156034239"><img src="http://www.yogahealth.net.au/webpics/facebook.gif" width="120" height="45" /></a></p>
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FYoga-Health-Townsville%2F140216156034239%23&amp;layout=box_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=700&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=50" scrolling="No" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:65px; height:65px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        <p>
          <a href="links.php" class="ArialGroup">Links to other Websites in our Community</a></p>
        <div class="quoteback">
        <a href="#" id="refresh"><img src="http://www.yogahealth.net.au/webpics/Refresh.gif" height="20px" width="20px" align="right" /></a>
         <div id="quote"><br \></div>
         </div>
         <br \>
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('YogaHealth1').start();
</script> 
         <?php include("templates/quotein.php"); ?>
      </div>
</div><div id="main"><?php include("editing/alignment.php"); ?></div></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your template file 404's; post the relevant code.

Comment: @Ross sorry the folder was templates not template fixed it now. Considering its php i will post the code anyway. What was i thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template should be a piece of code, which takes parameters and based on that generates output.

The solution for this problem could be, that in that accessed file, you declare a variable with appropriate name and pass it to the template. There you will have each page differentiated as requested.

**Solution**:

Magic constant `__FILE__` holds name of the included file, if used in include. So the solution is to move php code to the file, from which you are running the include.

Comment: Question is still open, my current patchwork solution is too split the template into two files and put the document name into the document that includes the template.

Comment: I see, I have found a specs that says, that __FILE__ always holds the name of the file/included_file. Thus your basename section will always see __FILE__ as the template. See here [php magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: What i did was I just moved the php script which finds the document name out of the included file so that it finds the correct document name.

Comment: I had already answered this myself in a comment, I am just hoping some web coding nut is gonna come around and provide the holy grail of a solution.